# What does pi mean in this BFS algorithm pseudocode?

Tags: algorithms, pseudocode, notation

I have the following pseudocode for *[breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)* algorithm

```
BFS(G,s)
 1 for each vertex u ∈ V(G) \ {s}
 2     color[u] = white
 3     d[u] = ∞
 4     π[u] = nil
 5 color[s] = gray
 6 d[s] = 0
 7 π[s] = nil
 8 Q = ∅
 9 Enqueue(Q,s)
10 while q ≠ ∅
11     u = Dequeue(Q)
12     for each v ∈ Adj[u]
13         if color[v] == white
14             color[v] = gray
15             d[v] = d[u] + 1
16             π[v] = u
17             Enqueue(Q,v)
18     color[u] = black
```

[Original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHAsW.png)

I do not understand what the letter π indicates in this context. I am not familiar with this algorithm and it is a difficult to guess.

I think `d` indicates the distance, `color` is of course the color, but that `π`... it appears to be a variable of some sort but I do not understand its function in this pseudocode.

Comment: *Is often the letter π used in pseudocode?*  Sometimes, but the meaning will vary depending on the context.

Comment: @Snowman: π here is not a function.  It is a mutable array of vertices indexed by vertices.

Comment: In this context π is just a symbol used in the algorithm, similar to d and color. Sometimes algorithm writers like to use single letter symbols rather than cute names like "parentVertices" or something that might tend to be used in a programming language.

Comment: @ChristopherWallace: algorithms are at least as much math as they are software development.

Comment: Now that this question has been reopened, can someone with sufficient moderator privileges please nuke the comments here? If I were landing on this page for the first time, they would add less than zero to my quest for knowledge...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe the use of π here is actual “parent of”. So in this case, the “parent” of *v*  is *u* because we're looking at all nodes adjacent to *u*. This verbiage can be found [here (PDF link)](https://web.archive.org/web/20171118044139/http://www.cs.cornell.edu/%7Ewdtseng/icpc/notes/graph_part1.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

The π vector surely keeps the node u with which you came in node v. This helps when you have to build the BFS tree of the graph. Although it is not necessary, this technique reduces a lot the complexity when you have to perform more time the BFS (ex. the [Edmonds–Karp algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmonds%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm) for computing the maximum flow between two nodes in a graph). In this case you don't have to run the BFS more times as you already have the BFS tree constructed and traverse it from the leaves to the root.